# django removing user table

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and creating my first app. I created a user model not understanding that there was one inbuilt. I have removed the user table.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.


# class User(models.Model):
#     firstname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
#     lastname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
#     email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
#     password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
#     newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=0)
#     accountlevel = models.BigIntegerField(default=1)
#     reportsCreated = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
#
#     def __str__(self):
#         return self.firstname +" "+ self.lastname +" - "+self.email



class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reports = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    accounttype = models.CharField(default='Free')
    monthlycost = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " - " + self.accounttype
```

**admin.py**
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from **future** import unicode_literals
    from .models import User
    from .models import Report

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Report)
```

I now need to like the ForeignKey from Account and report tables to the inbuilt user model.

when I run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get the following error

> django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model User is
>   already registered

Comment: can you provide the `admin.py` code

Answer (score 2):

Unregister the model from your app's `admin.py`.

**Remove below line**

```
admin.site.register(User)
```

Then `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: @ChrisEvans, Feel privileged to help you. Please vote up and select the answer, if it helped you. Thanks a lot for all the cooperation.